# Why won't cmdwiz display my bmp image converted from png by imagemagick?

Tags: cmd, imagemagick

My batch script generates a bmp preview image using imagemagick and I want to display it in a cmd window using cmdwiz but it won't show up.

I tried generating a png then converting it to a bmp with "-type truecolor" but it didn't work. It did work when I converted the png using MS Paint though.

Comment: You may need to tell Imagemagick to use an older BMP format. In the output, the prefacing with BMP3:image.bmp or BMP2:image.bmp.  The default is BMP4

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish the difference between the BMP that **ImageMagick** generates and the BMP that **MS Paint** generates to deduce what you need to tell **ImageMagick** to do differently. So, use:

```
magick identify -verbose IM.BMP > IM.TXT
magick identify -verbose MSPAINT.BMP > MSPAINT.TXT
```

Now use whatever tool Microsoft supplies to find the difference between `IM.TXT` and `MSPAINT.TXT`.

As an alternative, you can use `exiftool`, i.e.

```
exiftool IM.BMP
exiftool MSPAINT.BMP
```